# How to use webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin for optional conditional file loading

Tags: webpack

What I'm hoping to achieve is to have a single codebase for a web app and cordova app.

I want to have a folder/file structure that looks like this:

```
- components
  - component1.js
  - component2.js
  - component2.cordova.js
```

Ideally I want to continue to just use `import Component2 from 'component2'` wherever I import a component.

I will have a separate webpack.config file for each build, so was hoping I could get the cordova webpack config to look first for `component1.cordova.js`, and if it doesn't exist, fall back to `component1.js`.

It seems like [webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin) can do the looking for the cordova version, but I'm not sure if/how I can have it fall back to `component1.js` if `component1.cordova.js` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 11):

I believe no plugin is needed.

Here's what you need to do:

```
resolve: {
        root: [SRC_PATH, NODE_MODULES_PATH],
        fallback: NODE_MODULES_PATH,        
        extensions: ['.cordova.js','.js'],
}
```

The key is the `extensions` param. As you may have noticed, extensions are probed in the given order.

If you ever need to explicitly require one of the .js or .cordova.js you should specify the full file name, e.g : `require('components/c1.cordova.js')`

Note: `resolve` is at the root of the config object.

So the answer ends here, but there's more.

The added bonus of the `resolve.root` param is that you can now import by using paths relative to `SRC_PATH`  instead of the messy `../../../`

Of course, you need to have `NODE_MODULES_PATH` and `SRC_PATH` defined beforehand.

With this config you can write in any file in the SRC_PATH tree something like this:

```
import c from 'components/component1';
```

or

```
var c = require('components/component1')
```

Comment: This works like a charm to choose environment file (environment.prod.ts) when angular-cli was ejected ! Thanks !

Comment: fallback was replaced https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/ other than that this is a great solution thanks for sharing

Comment: The only problem is that the question is about how to use that plugin. In this sense, this answer is inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this is my solution:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
...
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\.ts$/, function(resource) {
    if (!resource.request.endsWith('.cordova.ts')) {
        var file_for_cordova = resource.request.replace(/\.ts$/, '.cordova.ts');
        if (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(resource.context, file_for_cordova))){
            resource.request = file_for_cordova;
          }
      }
}),
```

I think, it still not perfect and you can improve it